# when setting up a spring mvc project in intellij, how to you setup you tomcat/jetty?

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

When setting up a spring mvc project in intelliJ (community edition), how/where do you setup tomcat/jetty so when you click run it deploys to tomcat?

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat support's not included in the Community edition, you need Ultimate (which I recommend). Here's the [comparison](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html) of the two versions.

Comment: I can't believe they don't support tomcat??

Comment: They do, you just have to pay for it.

Comment: well that's what I meant, for 'free' they dont' support it.  I guess I can compile, then write a script to deploy to tomcat...

Answer (score 1):

It's quite old, but I know easy way to do it, so here it is...

As someone before mentioned there is no support, so we can use maven to do it. (Maven to manage dependencies is alway good idea, so I assume that you are using it).

http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin

This plugin allows you to easily specify which container you want. It automates building and deploying (I use it extensively, i.e. integration testing with Selenium). There are extensive examples of configuration on page.

After plugin is set up you have few cargo goals for your disposition. We have our interest in **cargo:run** which builds and deploys your application. This isn't rebuild-and-deploy-on-save from eclipse but I find it convenient and useful enough.

Last step is to add run configuration that runs this goal. Viola! You have easy deployment from your free IDE.

May seem little harsh but I use cargo everywhere and it's easy to setup. There is also fewer problems with refreshing content on server (had a lot of annoying issues on Eclipse). When you run on some serious problem just clean directory that cargo creates and it will set up fresh copy of your web continer.